# Regex with multiple optional grouping

Tags: c#, regex

We have a supplier that fires an HTTP post without using query strings. Effectively they post to our application in the following format:

```
www.mydomain.com/ourHandler/GroupId/ProductId/ItemId/CustomerId/
```

`ourHandler` (or Tracker) and `GroupId` is the only guaranteed values. The rest are completely optional.  The slash on the end could be missing, too.  I'm told that I need to cater for "hundreds of hits a second".

So I thought the best option might be to use a regex (which I suck at) instead of string.split.

Here's what I got but obviously it's not good enough:

```
^(?<tracker>.\w*)?/(?<GroupId>\w*)?/(?<ProductId>\w)?/(?<ItemId>\w*)?(/)?(?<CustomerId>\w*)?
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need Regex? Uri class has a `Segments` property

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.mydomain.com/ourHandler/GroupId/ProductId/ItemId/CustomerId/");
var segments = uri.Segments;
//ourHandler/ <-- segments[1] 
//GroupId/ <-- segments[2]
```